# Orbeon Forms: Initial data posted to the New Form page through XML POST

Tags: orbeon

For a Proof of Concept we are trying to prefill a Orbeon Form field when it loads for the user. The documentation on the Orbeon website states that such an action is possible when adding a additional POST payload to the call of the form-instance (“…/new?form-version=1”). We followed the guide on the Orbeon website (https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner/form-runner-detail-page#initial-data-posted-to-the-new-form-page), but whatever we try, the field is never prefilled in the page once loaded (or within the HTML we get back from the call in Windows Powershell.

What are we doing wrong in our example? Or is this simply not yet possible in the current version over Orbeon Forms?

---

In order to test the scenario we installed Orbeon on a VM-instance within our IT-landscape. Additionally we enabled the POST-methods on the forms ([https://doc.orbeon.com/xml-platform/controller/authorization-of-pages-and-services#backward-compatibility](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)).

We then made a very simple form in the Form Builder, with just one field to fill, and published the form so that is could be called through the “…/new”-url of the Form Runner.

[Orbeon Form example with empty field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IfTE.png)

[Orbeon Form field description/properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KEXq.png)

To access the Form with a payload we used PowerShell. Based on the documentation we tried a number of different approaches and XML-payloads, but non resulted in the field within the Form to be filled with the included value on load.

Below you can see one of the commands/payloads we tried:

```
$uri="http://##URL##/orbeon/fr/Test_PowerShell/Test_Powershell_prefilled_Formfield/new?form-version=1"$xmlbody = @"<form><section-1><grid-1><control-1-Powershell><xforms-input-1>NEWNEW</xforms-input-1></control-1-Powershell></grid-1></section-1></form>"@$encodedBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($xmlbody.ToCharArray())$body = @"<form method="post" action="/path/to/new"><input type="hidden" name="fr-form-data" value=$encodedBase64 /></form>"@
```

```
$callresponse = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -Method POST -body $body
```

```
$callresponse.content
```

As you can see below, the response of the call itself doesn’t contain any problems… just not the expected result of the field filled with the new value.

[XML POST call response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEGAg.jpg)

Hope someone can help and explain what we are doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get a chance to try the steps mentioned in my answer below on a verbatim install? If so did it work for you, and did it to help move things forward with the issue you were having? -Alex

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do the following to check that you can get this working on a verbatim install of Orbeon Forms:

1. [Download](https://www.orbeon.com/download) the latest Orbeon Forms PE.
2. Unzip the archive, unzip the `orbeon.war` into an `orbeon` directory, move it to your Tomcat's `webapps`.
3. Rename `orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config/properties-local.xml.template` to remove the `.template`, edit the file, and add the 2 properties below.

   ```xml
   <property as="xs:string" processor-name="oxf:page-flow" name="page-    public-methods"    value="GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE"/>
   <property as="xs:string" processor-name="oxf:page-flow" name="service-public-methods" value="GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE"/>
   ```
4. Create a form in Form Builder, and in Edit Source paste the `form.xml` from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/avernet/95d97c2b41e36bb32d1258d1089e9035). Publish it.
5. Save the `data.xml` from that gist. From the command line, run: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d @data.xml http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/a/a/new > new.html`
6. Open `new.html` in an editor, and search for "Homer". You should be able to find it as the value of an input field.

Once this is working for you with a verbatim install, you can look into what is different in your actual environment that could explain the difference you are seeing. And of course, feel free to comment here should you have any questions.